# Javascript style's error

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, styles

my JS script send me that bug:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
>       at myFunction ((index):1368)
>       at HTMLDivElement.onclick ((index):1354) myFunction @ (index):1368 onclick @ (index):1354

Here is my code:

```js
function myFunction() {

  var y = document.getElementById("woocommerce_product_categories-1");
  var x = document.getElementById("shop-sidebar");

  console.log("x.style.display1");

  x.style.display = 'none';

  console.log("x.style.display");

  if (x.style.display == "none") {
    y.style.display = "none";
    x.style.position = "fixed";
    x.style.display = "block";
    x.style.zIndex = 9;
    x.style.top = "126px";
    x.style.width = "100%";
    x.style.background = "#fff";
    x.style.height = "calc(100vh - 126px)";
    x.style.overflowY = "scroll";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
    x.style.zIndex = 0;
  }

  var x = document.getElementById("menu-mobile-header");
  if (x.style.position === "absolute") {
    x.style.position = "fixed";
  } else {
    x.style.position = "absolute";
  }
  var x = document.getElementById("menu-mobile-header");
  if (x.style.top === "195px") {
    x.style.top = "60px";
  } else {
    x.style.top = "195px";
  }
  var x = document.getElementById("menu-mobile-header");
  if (x.style.zIndex === "0") {
    x.style.zIndex = "9";
  } else {
    x.style.zIndex = "0";
  }


}
```

```html
<?php if(is_product_category())
{ ?>

<div id="menu-mobile-header">
  <div class="menu-mobile-header" onclick="myFunction()">Filtern</div>
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

Console.log send me message with x.style.display1 but in second message I have bug.

Also i noticed that code working but without php.

Maybe somebody know why I can't use any style's in JS?

Have a nice day!

Comment: Don't know if it is a typo, but you are missing the closing `}` for `myFunction()`

Comment: "*Also i noticed that code working but without php.*", did you check your rendered HTML, are the elements `#woocommerce_product_categories-1` and `#shop-sidebar` present in your code???

Comment: Sorry for this comment, but why do you use x.style.whatever multiple times for every css property you need instead of adding a class to the element using `x.className += 'myClass'` or `x.classList.add('myClass')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `x` is `null`.

You create `x` (line 8) with `document.getElementById` but you don't have a DOM element with the `id="shop-sidebar"` attribute.